# Creating public types in AutoFixture 4.8.0 using internal JSON constructors, with many constructor arguments

Tags: c#, autofixture

As at AutoFixture 4.8.0, is there a better alternative to using `Fixture.Register` to register a function to create a type that exposes only an `internal` constructor?

#### In context:

I'm working on a .net standard class library to build API for internal use. We do not want to expose public constructors and as such all constructors for these models are `internal`. Properties are additionally `public readonly`. These classes will be instantiated through Json deserialization, and in this particular library there is a model with > 20 properties to consider. As a bonus, we'd like to use [AutoDataAttribute] where possible.

ie. is there an alternative to supplying an internal jsonconstructor with a mixture of non and complex types (also internal) with 20+ arguments using AutoFixture?

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class Tests
{
    private Fixture _fixture;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture();

        _fixture.Register(() => new Vehicle(_fixture.Create<string>(), _fixture.Create<int>()));

        _fixture.Register(
            () => new Driver(_fixture.Create<string>(), _fixture.Create<int>(), _fixture.Create<Vehicle>()));
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanCreateDriverWithVehicle()
    {
        Func<Driver> func = () => _fixture.Create<Driver>();
        func.Should().NotThrow(); // Green
    }
}

[PublicAPI]
public sealed class Driver
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int Age;
    public Vehicle Vehicle;

    [JsonConstructor]
    internal Driver(string name, int age, Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Vehicle = vehicle;
    }
}

[PublicAPI]
public sealed class Vehicle
{
    public readonly string Manufacturer;
    public readonly int Miles;

    [JsonConstructor]
    internal Vehicle(string manufacturer, int miles)
    {
        Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        Miles = miles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default AutoFixture considers the public constructors only. It doesn't pick up the internal constructors, even if they are accessible from the test execution assembly (not even sure whether there is a reasonable technical possibility to check that).

You can easily customize your fixture to support that. Get inspiration from the following code sample:

```
[Fact]
public void ShouldActivateTypesWithInternalConstructor()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(
        new Postprocessor(
            new MethodInvoker(
                new ModestInternalConstructorQuery()),
            new AutoPropertiesCommand()
        ));

    var result = fixture.Create<TypeWithInternalConstructor>();

    Assert.NotEqual(0, result.Property);
}

public class ModestInternalConstructorQuery : IMethodQuery
{
    public IEnumerable<IMethod> SelectMethods(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));

        return from ci in type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            where ci.IsAssembly // Take internal constructors only
            let parameters = ci.GetParameters()
            where parameters.All(p => p.ParameterType != type)
            orderby parameters.Length ascending
            select new ConstructorMethod(ci) as IMethod;
    }
}

public class TypeWithInternalConstructor
{
    public int Property { get; }

    internal TypeWithInternalConstructor(int property)
    {
        Property = property;
    }
}
```

Comment: for me it does not work, please see also my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477706/create-type-with-internal-constructor-and-self-referencing-constructor-parameter), thanks!